# Why isn't concat recognized in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I ran this test query on different computers. Some of them don't recognize the concatenation

```
SEL concat ('test', 'test', 'test') 
FROM testTable
```

All of these computers run the same SQL Assistant and hit the same Teradat database version 14

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CONCAT` is not a Standard/Teradata SQL function but part of [ODBC](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_00/Connectivity/B035_2509_034K/2509ch06.08.22.html#ww13919714). You submit the query using ODBC and the driver *might* replace it with valid SQL based on some options.

You should always avoid those functions, in SQL Assistant better check *Disable Parsing* in the ODBC options. And then learn to use correct Teradata SQL instead, if your case it's simply `SELECT 'test' || 'test' || 'test'`

Comment: Thank you very much    I can't find `check Disable Parsing in the ODBC` . Is this in SQL assistant ?

Comment: @Emily: It's in the ODBC Datasource Administration, press *Configure* and then *Options*